# Get all rows where duplicate values exist in several different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like so:

```
id     first_name     last_name     address     city_state_zip
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Bob            Smith         123 Place   Georgetown, TN  38119
2      Bob            Smith         123 Place   Georgetown, TN  38119
3      Bobby          Smith         123 Place   Georgetown, TN  38119
```

I want a query that will allow me to retrieve all rows that have, for this example, have the same first 3 characters of the first name AND first 3 characters of last name AND all characters of address AND all characters of city/state/zip. This is the query I have, but when I run it I get zero rows returned:

```
SELECT
  P1.id,
  P1.first_name,
  P1.last_name,
  P1.address,
  P1.city_state_zip
FROM person P1
JOIN (SELECT
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name
  FROM person
  GROUP BY id, 
    first_name,
    last_name,
    address,
    city_state_zip
  HAVING (count(left(first_name, 3)) > 1
    AND count(left(last_name, 3)) > 1
    AND count(address + city_state_zip) > 1)) P2 ON P2.id = P1.id
```

Comment: Learn normalization.  This is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Have a derived table that selects the "duplicate" only. GROUP BY etc.

Comment: Rather constraints and sanitize input data issue...

Comment: `group by id` will make sure that each group contains only one record. Therefore, because of the having clause, nothing is returned. I do not really understand what you want to achieve. Could you tell this in normal words? do you want to find duplicates to eliminate them later? So getting the id-groups would be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery - you just need to JOIN the table against itself, and specify your ON clauses well.

Something like:

```
select *
from person p1
JOIN person p2
ON
    p1.ID != p2.ID  -- because you don't want the line to match to itself
    AND left(p1.first_name,3) = left(p2.first_name,3)
    AND left(p1.last_name,3) = left(p2.last_name,3)
    AND ... etc, etc
```

... oh, and make sure you've got indexes on all/most of the columns, otherwise this is going to be very slow on large tables.

Answer (score 0):

My take is to join the table on an aggregated version of it. The aggregated version has only the duplicates' information at hand.

```
SELECT *
FROM person AS P1
INNER JOIN (
    --#region
    SELECT
        first_name = SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 3)
      , last_name = SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 3)
      , address
      , city_state_zip
    FROM person
    GROUP BY
        SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 3)
      , SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 3)
      , address
      , city_state_zip
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    --#endregion
) AS P2
    ON P2.first_name = SUBSTRING(P1.first_name, 1, 3)
   AND P2.last_name = SUBSTRING(P1.last_name, 1, 3)
   AND P2.address = P1.address
   AND P2.city_state_zip = P1.city_state_zip
```

If it performs poorly, try running the aggregation alone and storing it in a @table variable or a temporary #table, then running the join on that.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
SELECT * FROM person p1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 3) first_name, SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 3)last_name, [address], city_state_zip
FROM person 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 3) , SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 3), [address], city_state_zip)
p2 ON p1.SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 3) = p2.first_name
    AND p1.SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 3) = p2.last_name
    AND p1.[address] = p2.[address]
    AND p1.city_state_zip = p2.city_state_zip
```